# Is it possible to retain the union of user privileges and root privileges when using sudo?

Tags: root, nfs

This question is similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/q/65048/107789), but should hopefully be more clearly expressed.

Assume that `/home` is an NFS-mounted directory, and the NFS server has root squashing enabled.
Consider the following script, which requires root privileges to read a file, and normal user privileges to write a file.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /etc/shadow
touch ~/shadow
```

If this script is run without `sudo`, then the user cannot read `/etc/shadow`. However, if the script is run with `sudo`, root cannot write to `~/shadow`, due to root squashing.

**Is it possible to grant user privileges to root when running this script, so that it can work successfully as one script without needing to include `sudo` on each of the commands that need it?**

I am trying to avoid using `sudo` inside the script for reasons mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-sudo-command-inside-a-script/425762#comment551543_425754).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and appropriate for you to enable root squashing?  Do note that `Turdon`'s comment on the subject is not an absolute rule, just a suggestion which simplifies things.  There is really no reason to have a `sudo` inside your script.  The problem begins when you add a few and try to pass parameters and environment variables to it.

Comment: @JuliePelletier, I think you meant disable root squashing. However, I do not have control over the NFS server, so I cannot disable root squashing.

Comment: Then run your script as a regular user.  If you want to combine `sudo` operations, then put those in a separate script that you'd call `sudo script`.

Comment: Oh, and a final note:  be careful about your system's security if you start to copy and open access to the contents from `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: @JuliePelletier, I'm not doing anything with `/etc/shadow`. I only used it as an easily recognizable example of something that required root privileges. The actual script I'm running is manipulating cpusets and running experiments, so it needs to freely interleave commands that require root privileges and commands that write to my home directory.
The current workaround is to write everything to a local directory, change permissions, and then copy the output to my home directory, but this is rather inefficient.

Comment: I reread your question and I think you're overthinking this.  Did you try creating a file with your own user and then writing to it as root?

Comment: @JuliePelletier, That does not work unless I make the file globally writeable. The current alternate workaround is to make my data directory globally writeable, but that seems undesirable from a security standpoint.

Comment: Still, if adding a `sudo` in your script solves your existential question, please use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can run a script as `sudo`. But, you can modify the script to relinquish root privileges wherever not needed or in your case, when working on `nfs` file system.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /etc/shadow
su -c 'touch ~/shadow' - <some_user>
```

Comment: Oh come on.  OP is trying to get rid of `sudo` inside their script and you suggest they use `su` to lower their privileges.  lol

Comment: I know. Unless, OP goes SELinux or 'AppArmour' way, there is no easy way out. An interesting riddle to solve.

Comment: @Julie Pelletier, OP was asking a way to avoid sudo inside the script. So, I thought, probably this is best way out.

Comment: also one should add a check to exit if not root and the script is expecting you to be.